# CSS Can I make a div with fixed background attachment scroll slower?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create some cool parallax effects and was windering if I can make a div with a bg image that has the property `background-attachement: fixed` scroll a bit (slower than normal scroll) instead of having it stand still?

this is what my css looks like:

```
.parallax{
    height: 400px !important;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

this is my div

```
<div class="parallax" style="background-image: url('img/image.jpg'); ">
</div>
```

I've tried this:

```
$('div.parallax').each(function(){
        $scroll_speed = 10;
        $this = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $bgScroll = -(($win.scrollTop() - $this.offset().top)/ $scroll_speed);
            $bgPosition = 'center '+ $bgScroll + 'px';
            $this.css({ backgroundPosition: $bgPosition });
        });
});
```

Seems to be working, only I cant increase the scroll_speed even though I change the variable anyone can help me out?

Comment: No, you can't. Yes, you need JS or Jquery. Just look at some samples here: https://jsfiddle.net/apederson/z93R7/

Comment: Just use a plugin: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

Comment: @miro I've added the jquery I tried check out edited OP

Comment: @freedomnm I've tried something with jQuery but is not working 100% correctly, check out edited OP if you want :)

Comment: Here's a guide on making parallax effects with pure css: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the scroll speed can be easily done by changing the factor. A factor of 5 would be *faster* scroll speed, while 20 would be *slower* scroll speed.

```js
$('div.parallax').each(function() {
  $scroll_speed = 5;
  $this = $(this);
  $('#container').scroll(function() {
    $bgScroll = -(($('#container').scrollTop() - $this.offset().top) / $scroll_speed);
    $bgPosition = 'center ' + $bgScroll + 'px';
    $this.css({
      backgroundPosition: $bgPosition
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.parallax {
  height: 400px !important;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
#container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="parallax" style="background-image: url('http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/jack_and_jill.png'); ">
    bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>bla bla bla
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```